# Left Click on Bing Maps and WPF doesnt work properly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, bing-maps

I'm creating a WPF application that use the Bing Maps. I put it in a page control that at the same time is called from an iframe control. At the begining it displayed the Map and I can zoom in and out without a problem.
The thing is, that when I click the Map with the left button of my mouse what it does is to go down a little bit of the current location and a zoom in is done automatically instead of holding the point where the click was done to do a kind of drag and drop. Just like Google Maps does.

Here is my XAML code:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <TextBlock Text="News page" FontSize="32" />

    <m:Map CredentialsProvider="..."
           Center="25.6732109,-100.309201" ZoomLevel="12" Mode="Road"/>

</Grid>
```

I'm using the following assembly reference: **xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF"**

Does any one know how can I fix it?

Regards!

Comment: Hi MikePR, I have not used the map control before and cannot tell you what the problem is. But you could try using this Free Map Control by DevExpress. I know it's not an answer but it might help. http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/thinking/archive/2011/12/02/wpf-map-control-it-39-s-free-to-all-msdn-subscribers.aspx

Comment: Hi thanks for the tip. However, the free version is only with the MSDN Suscirptions and seems it has expired :-(. Thanks any way

Answer (score 0):

If you use the mouse up or down events on the Map control this will work fine. The map itself doesn't expose a Click event of it's own, but you don't need that if you use the mouse up/down events.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution was to add a MouseDown Event to the map:

```xml
<m:Map                
    CredentialsProvider="<your Credentials>"
    Center="{Binding Center, Mode=TwoWay}"
    ZoomLevel="10"
    MouseDown="Map_MouseDown">
</m:Map>
```

In the code behind you can add:

```
private void Map_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

This handles the event and no further processing is done. After this moving and draging the Map worked as usual maps do.